# Using Powershell's bitwise operators

Tags: powershell, bit-manipulation

I'm looking for example of how I would solve the scenario below:

Imagine my printer has the following property for "Status"
0 -Offline
2 -Paper Tray Empty
4 -Toner Exhausted
8 -Paper Jam

When I query status it returns a value of 12.  I can obviously see that this means the printer has the Toner Exhausted and a Paper Jam,  but how would I work this out with Powershell?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The boolean bitwise and operator in Powershell is `-band`.

Assume you define your values and descriptions in a hashtable, and have the value of 12 from the printer:

```
 $status = @{1 = "Offline" ; 2 = "Paper Tray Empty" ; 4 = "Toner Exhausted" ; 8 = "Paper Jam" }
 $value = 12
```

Then, this statement will give you the textual descriptions:

```
$status.Keys | where { $_ -band $value } | foreach { $status.Get_Item($_) }
```

You *could* define the enum in Powershell, but the above works just as well, [and defining enums in Powershell seems like a lot of work](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/01/23/how-to-create-enum-in-powershell.aspx).

[Here is an article](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/bitwise-operations/), that talks about how to use the bitwise operators in Powershell.

Comment: The last article URL does not exist anymore

Comment: Thanks, found another one to link to (the fallacies of 8-year old answers...)

Comment: 10 years later, I'm just finally coming into interest in this bitwise stuff and found this answer incredibly helpful.  Belated thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can let PowerShell do more of the work for you.  Here's an example using System.IO.FileOptions:

```
PS> [enum]::GetValues([io.fileoptions]) | ?{$_.value__ -band 0x90000000}
RandomAccess
WriteThrough
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, do you happen to know if it's possible to enumerate the values of the UserAccountControl attribute for a user in AD?

Comment: If the attribute is a .NET attribute then yes.  You just need to specify the full typename to [enun]::GetValues().